# Is there a difference between Exception and RuntimeException in PHP?

Tags: php, exception

What is the exact semantic difference between `\Exception` and `\RuntimeException` in PHP? When we should use the former and when the latter?

Comment: Exception is the generic exception class that other exceptions extend. RuntimeException, and others, are there to provide additional semantic meaning to the exception you are throwing. [PHP Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php). [RuntimeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php). Ideally, you should throw the exception class that is most suitable for the error. I often use the generic Exception in my catch blocks to catch any type of exception.

Comment: Could you show me examples? I always use \RuntimeException. A collegue of mine uses \Exception.

Comment: Both are correct but `RuntimeException` is more specific. it tells that the exception can happen only while the program is running

Comment: Both are very generic exceptions. You can use both almost interchangeably

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅, out of curiosity, an example of an exception that can happen when the program is NOT running, in PHP?

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅, ... also \Exception can happen while program is running. Or not?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is much semantic difference at all. If you are choosing what to `throw`, these two have nothing on each other.

Comment: to be more precise, the program will always be running. The `RuntimeException` is opposed to `LogicException` : the `LogicException` needs a code fix to make the program run again whereas the `RuntimeException` can be caused by bad user input

Comment: Much better. And better than the accepted answer. :)

Comment: this is all messed up

Comment: Why? And where, ... @user2502025 ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Exception is a base class of all exceptions in PHP (including [RuntimeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php)). 
As the documentation says:

> RuntimeException is thrown if an error which can only be found on
>   runtime occurs.

It means that whenever You are expecting something that normally should work, to go wrong eg: division by zero or array index out of range etc. You can throw RuntimeException.

As for [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), it is a very generic exception and I would call it a "last resort". You can add it as a last one in "try" just to be sure You are handling all exceptions.

Example:

```
try {
    //code...
} catch(RuntimeException $e) {
    echo ("RuntimeException..."); 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo ("Error something went wrong!"); 
    var_dump($e); 
}
```

Hope it is a clear now.

Comment: So, you suggest to use \RuntimeException but also \Exception as "last resort" catch ... ?

Comment: Using only `Exception` you would also catch `RuntimeException` since it inherits from `Exception`. It's all about semantic.

Comment: @sensorario I suggest to use both if You know it can occur and the way You are handling it is different from all other types of exceptions. If all You do after catching an exception is print a message into a log file then it would be faster to use only generic Exception since You do not have to spend additional time on writing those lines ;)

Comment: the question was about semantic. "something that normally should work, to go wrong" is not enough explanation, because you can explain `Exception` in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference between those two is semantic. The `\RuntimeException` inherits from `\Exception`. Basically there are no other differences.

You can create your own exceptions inheriting from both of above, the most common usage is to inheritit from `\Exception`.

Answer (score 3):

> RuntimeException is thrown if an error which can only be found on runtime occurs.

The key word here is *found*. Some summaries say that a RuntimeException *happens* when the program is running. That's redundant: all errors & exceptions happen when the program is running. The key difference is that a RuntimeException is caused by bad data, not by bad coding logic, so it cannot be found by analysing the code before it is run.

That said, there is no *technical* difference between them: RuntimeException inherits from Exception. But keeping them separate may help you to keep the logic clear in your own brain (i.e., the difference is semantic), and to catch different types of exceptions in different places, and deal with them separately.

You can always create your own exception classes, for similar semantic meanings to further subdivide your exceptions, or to actually add extra functionality. Your own exception classes may inherit from RuntimeException or from LogicException, or more simply directly from Exception. Inheriting directly from Exception seems to be the norm. Think about it and do what makes sense to you. Once again, there is no difference in how PHP itself treats these exception classes.

Answer (score 1):

If we’re talking about the semantic difference, I would say that `\Exception` doesn’t have any semantics. The `\Exception` is so general that we can only say that this is an exception and nothing else. We cannot even say what this exception is related to if we don't have any additional context. On the contrary, the `\RuntimeException` is more specific and, thereby, it has some semantics.

According to the [RuntimeException class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) documentation `Exception thrown if an error which can only be found on runtime occurs.`. So, the semantics is that this exception is strongly related to the runtime. To me, it means that the problem happens during the execution stage and mostly has dynamic nature.

Comment: Yes. Actually now I replace all kind of exceptions into a domain exceptions.